# Are $C$ and $C\times C$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

> Are $C$ and $C\times C$ homeomorphic? (Here, $C$ denotes the "first middle third" Cantor set.)

Seems that they are but I can't come up with an idea how to show it.

Comment: Yes. They are. There is a characterization of the Cantor set as the unique-up-to-homeomorphism totally disconnected compact Polish space without isolated points.

Comment: Also, if you view $C$ as $2^ω$, it is almost obvious.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034989.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Cantor set $C$ is homeomorphic to $C \times C$. The Wikipedia article on [Cantor spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space) seems to contain enough information to answer your question. Quoting parts of the article below:

> [A] topological space is a Cantor space if it is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.
>
> . . .
>
> [T]he canonical example of a Cantor space is the countably infinite topological product of the discrete $2$-point space $\{0, 1\}$. This is usually written as $2^\mathbb{N}$ or $2^\omega$ (where $2$ denotes the $2$-element set $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology).
>
> . . .
>
> [M]any properties of Cantor spaces can be established using $2^\omega$, because its construction as a product makes it amenable to analysis.
>
> Cantor spaces have the following properties:
>
> - . . .
> - The product of two (or even any finite or countable number of) Cantor spaces is a Cantor space.